# Is there a way to use Bundler for production gems?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I tried searching for this several times, but if this question has been answered already I didn't find it.

So, let's say I've developed a plain old gem (not a Rails app). I already know how to use Bundler for development, so I have a Gemfile and everything in my repository. However, I want this gem to use Bundler for dependency resolution when I install it, not just when I work on it.

Is there a way to do so, or would I have to resort to running its commands from a git checkout with bundle exec?

Answer (score 1):

Bundler resolves dependencies not only for development. Just run `bundle install` on production server after deployment and it will install all needed gems there too.

If you need to install gems from several repositories, add row in you Gemfile:

`source 'http://you_repository.com`

Comment: Would this work even if "deployment" consisted of packaging my code as a gem and installing it on the production server? Or, in other words, is there a way to install this gem in such a way that it will use bundler to resolve its dependencies when you run one of its executables?

Comment: If your gem is install on production server (it is in gem list), and it is in Gemfile, bundler will use it.